# ClassLoader doesn't seem to be returning object correctly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, classloader

I have a class MyClass that implements an interface ToTest, that I want to retrieve through a ClassLoader in my Web App running on Tomcat.

The class is below:

```
public class MyClass implements ToTest {
    public String doStuff(String input) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the interface is

```
public interface ToTest {
    public String doStuff(String input);
}
```

When I instantiate a normal instance of the class, it works correctly (i.e. appears to be an instance of ToTest), however, when I use my class loader, the object does not resolve as an instance of ToTest.

i.e.

```
Object myObject = new MyClass();
if (myObject instanceof ToTest) {
    System.out.println("This is a ToTest");
}
```

will print out the message, whereas:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("c:\\tomcatfolder\\wtpwebapps\\MyApp\\WEB-INF\\classes").toURI().toURL()});
Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("MyClass");
Object myOtherObj = loadedClass.newInstance();
if (myOtherObj instanceof ToTest) {
    System.out.println("This is a ToTest");
}
```

returns an object that appears to be a MyClass object, but the 'if instanceof' returns false.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information. Have you put some jar files into the system class path, and others into the webapp?

Comment: Not sure I understand the relevance of the question - the ClassLoader should pick up the class from the specified location, which is where the .class file is deployed too ?

Comment: I am tempted to downvote... why are you creating your own classloader?

Comment: My Classloader is to load a dynamically created class within the app at a later date

Comment: So you are planning to generate Java source, compile it, copy it on web app class loader, later maybe remove or modify it... good luck with that ;).

Comment: Don't forget the Threading and Security Manager too ...!

Comment: @PavelHoral Java classloading is messy but it's possbile. I once worked in a similar project where Java code was generated, compiled and loaded dynamically at runtime. Assuming OP presented us a simplified example of his actual problem, this is a totally valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because if you load the same class with a different classloader, it's considered a different class. One could even simplify your problem:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("c:\\tomcatfolder\\wtpwebapps\\MyApp\\WEB-INF\\classes").toURI().toURL()});
Class<MyClass> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("MyClass");
Object myOtherObj = loadedClass.newInstance(); //loaded by URLClassLoader
Object myObject = new MyClass(); // loaded by default classloader
// at this point the two objects don't have the same type
```

If we look at your actual problem, we see that `myOtherObj` is loaded from a different classloader than `ToTest` which you compare it to. This means that it's class `MyClass` doesn't implement the same `ToTest` as the one you use for comparison.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.4):

> "At run time, several reference types with the same binary name may be loaded simultaneously by different class loaders. These types may or may not represent the same type declaration. Even if two such types do represent the same type declaration, they are considered distinct."

and

> "Two reference types are the same run-time type if [...] They are both class or both interface types, are defined by the same class loader, and have the same binary name [...]"

As bmargulies pointed out you might be able to avoid this by setting the current class loader as parent of your custom one:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("c:\\tomcatfolder\\wtpwebapps\\MyApp\\WEB-INF\\classes").toURI().toURL()}, getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Great stuff - I added the parent Classloader to my classloader and the problem was solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Guys, please... the suggested solution is nonsense. You can not define classloader on the same path as your parent class loader. That makes the child useless.

Comment: @PavelHoral I agree. Since I don't know the structure of OPs classpath it's hard to tell if it works. E.g. it would make sense if the interface and implementing class are in different places in the classpath. That's why I wrote "might" ;-)

Comment: Actually, I agree too - I can just use getClass().getClassLoader() to load the instance of the class. This has enlightened me on Class Loaders though, so don't feel your time has been wasted! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You did not set your new class loader to inherit from your old class loader. So, it does not share any classes with your existing class loader. So, no object created reflectively from your class loader will ever be instanceof any of your classes.

I don't see why you would want this class loader, but if you do you need to set up the parent.